# How to find a node with xpath having namespace in xml

Tags: selenium, xpath

I am trying to find div node with Xpath for selenium. here div having categories/Accounts & Contacts as value of ext:tree-node-id need to be selected, but as ext:tree-node-id is a namespace my below xpath is not working.

```
    //li[@class='x-tree-node']//div[contains(.,ext:tree-node-id='categories\/Accounts & Contacts')]
//li[@class='x-tree-node']//div[@ext:tree-node-id='categories\/Accounts & Contacts']


 <li class="x-tree-node">
<div class="x-tree-node-el x-unselectable folder x-tree-node-collapsed" unselectable="on" ext:tree-node-id="categories\/Accounts & Contacts">
<span class="x-tree-node-indent"/>
<img class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow-plus" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt=""/>
<img class="x-tree-node-icon" unselectable="on" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt=""/>
<a class="x-tree-node-anchor" tabindex="1" href="" hidefocus="on">
</div>
<ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style="display: none;">
</li>
<li class="x-tree-node">
<div class="x-tree-node-el x-unselectable folder x-tree-node-collapsed" unselectable="on" ext:tree-node-id="categories\/Opportunities">
<span class="x-tree-node-indent"/>
<img class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow-plus" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt=""/>
<img class="x-tree-node-icon" unselectable="on" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt=""/>
<a class="x-tree-node-anchor" tabindex="1" href="" hidefocus="on">
</div>
<ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style="display: none;">
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

A colon in the attribute will not allow the xpath works. You need to improve a little to it works as you wish, like:

`//li[@class='x-tree-node']//div[@*[contains(local-name(), tree-node-id)] = 'categories\\/Accounts & Contacts']`

The "local-name" will select the name after the colon named "tree-node-id".

Comment: This xpath is also not finding the node.